# Default form input value not recognised by form validator in controller

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-9

I have a form in which some inputs are disabled but have default values generated and set before the form loads (I can see the default values on the form inputs which are disabled). On form submission, the controller validates the form values before creating an entry in the database. My problem is the disabled inputs with the default values are being seen as blank and I keep getting an error that the input values are requried

HTML

```
                  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{ route('admins.store') }}">
              @csrf                     
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Admin Names</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="name">
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('name'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Admin ID</label>
                      <input type="text" name="adminID" value="{{ $adminID }}" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('adminID') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="adminID" disabled>
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('adminID'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('adminID') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Admin Email</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="email">
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('email'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif                           
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Phone Number</label>
                      <input type="text" name="phonenumber" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('phonenumber') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="phonenumber">
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('phonenumber'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('phonenumber') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif                           
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Access Level</label>
                      <input type="text" name="accessLevel" value="admin" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('accessLevel') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="accessLevel" disabled>
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('accessLevel'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('accessLevel') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif                          
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="bmd-label-floating">Password</label>
                      <input type="text" name="password" value="{{ $password }}" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('accessLevel') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="password" disabled>
                      <!-- Error -->
                      @if ($errors->has('password'))
                      <div class="error">
                          {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                      </div>
                      @endif                         
                    </div>
                  </div>                                             
                </div>                                                                          
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Admin</button>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </form>
```

Controller:

```
if(Auth::check())
    {        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phonenumber' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:10',
            'adminID'=>'required',
            'accessLevel'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required' 
        ]);

        $admin = Admin::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
```

Comment: Disabled inputs are not submitted with the form. Could try the `readonly` attribute

Comment: Thanks @brombeer. readonly attribute worked